# Sharepoint Intranet is running slow

Tags: 2010

I have SharePoint installed on a server, a Development Server currently running Spiceworks WEBUI based Network Management system and SugarCRM . . . and they're both performing quite well.

the Development Server is a Intel Xeon E562 with Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit installed on it and has 16GB ram . . .

however SharePoint is installed on it as well, it was working quite fine when it was installed, and now, three months later, its extremely slow.

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most of time slow environment causes are (at SharePoint level):

- Content DB and other Service + Logging DB sizes
- Wrongly configured Search Crawling, Indexing & Timer services
- Issues with storage devices ( SAN/NAT or any windows indexing service)
- Too many web applications & sites

(at windows level)
- File system indexing service
- Issues in paging

Observe the settings and post your findings so we can help more